# How to set upper limit for dispatch_semaphore_t

Tags: ios, semaphore

I just realized that there's no API to set the upper limit of the dispatch_semaphore_t, I wish the semaphore upper limit can be 1, that the wait can still work even I over signaled the semaphore, however I tested the following code, the wait doesn't work, Can anybody let me know how to set the upper limit of the dispatch_semaphore_t?

```
  - (dispatch_semaphore_t)taskSemaphore {
      if (!_taskSemaphore) {
        _taskSemaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1);
      }
      return _taskSemaphore;
    }

  - (void)testMethod {
     dispatch_semaphore_signal([self taskSemaphore]);
     dispatch_semaphore_signal([self taskSemaphore]);
     dispatch_semaphore_signal([self taskSemaphore]);
     dispatch_semaphore_signal([self taskSemaphore]);
     dispatch_semaphore_signal([self taskSemaphore]);

     dispatch_semaphore_wait([self taskSemaphore], DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
     dispatch_semaphore_wait([self taskSemaphore], DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
     dispatch_semaphore_wait([self taskSemaphore], DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
  }
```

Comment: If you only want to allow one at a time, use a lock of some sort. `@synchronized`, `[NSLock lock]`, `pthread_mutex` (probably not a good idea at your experience level), or just a serial dispatch queue.

Comment: No, that's not my point, I just raised an example here, it can be 2 or 3

Comment: Then I'm pretty sure there's no way to make an arbitrary limit. I'm sure one could concoct a helper method for it, but that's probably not the best solution. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/172958). What's the end result you think you need this for?

Comment: Like limit the concurrent number of the dispatched task, however, for avoiding deadlock, the semaphore can be over signaled when the asynchronous dispatched task was done with different branches

Comment: Don't you think it should be a quite normal requirement for setting the upper limit of a semaphore? many kinds of semaphore creating API in other platform support to set this limit

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to set an upper limit for `dispatch_semaphore_t`. The implementation most likely rather primitive. Going by the return value, it probably uses a `long` internally, so the upper limit is probably `LONG_MAX`. This `long` is atomically increased or decreased and any decrease that doesn't cause the `long` to go below zero results in a successful operation, otherwise the `long` is increased again and the thread is blocked. Once blocked, it is either woken up by the timeout, if one has been set, causing the operation to fail with timeout, or it is woken up every time the `long` has been atomically increased by some other thread, causing the code to give it another try. This try may also fail, which may happen as two waiting threads can be woken up and run at the same time, in which case one will be faster, the other one will then block again and still wait for timeout or another increase. If you need anything beyond the rather primitive API, you need to build your own semaphore, which is a rather easy thing to do based upon `NSLock` and a primitive counter.